# Syntax Error in VBA Code - Run Time error '-2147217900(80040e14)'

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have another issue now that we have decided to move things to a server since the database cannot handle the amount of data being captured.

The short of it is:

I have tried using my existing code via transferspreadsheet method to import data to a tmp file but this is taking to long now with the SQL Server. I would like to stay with doing this programmatically and have been working with the following code. I am not sure if this will work since I can't get past the syntax error. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated

code start:

```
Dim CN As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strXLSource As String
Dim lngRecsaff As Long

strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=logistics.companyname.com;Database=ITM;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set CN = New ADODB.Connection

CN.Open strConn

strXLSource = ("C:\Users\GONZW053\Documents\My Desktop Documents\Monster Database Exports\DTPM - WDW DLR\book1.xlsx;Extended Properties= Excel 12.0")

strSQL = "INSERT INTO [tmpWDWDLR] SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source = '" & strXLSource & "')"
Debug.Print strSQL
CN.Execute strSQL, lngRecsaff, adExecuteNoRecords
Debug.Print "Records Affected: " & lngRecsaff

CN.close
Set CN = Nothing
```

I look forward to the help as this site and contributors have been a great source of knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: This plain can't work. `OPENDATASOURCE` requires the Excel file to be on the server, and it's on your local machine. You will have to insert the excel file through `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` or using queries and linked tables. Also, a runtime error and a syntax error are different things. Which one is it?

Comment: Erik,The message that comes up is Run Time Error with the above mentioned code and in the body of the message is a syntax error. The docmd.transferspreadsheet method is taking up to an hour for some files to be uploaded and also error-ing out due to "Exceeded Memory" from Access.

Comment: Ah, that's a runtime error in VBA because your SQL contains a syntax error. Personally, I recommend using queries instead of VBA to achieve this. Will share an example soon

Comment: Thank you Erik. I appreciate the help. I have Access built in Append queries set up but it is just taking to darn long. I want to make the process easier for those who come in behind me should I be hit by a Bus tomorrow. The main concept is to first delete the master table, import data from excel through access to the tmp table on the server and then finally merge all tmp tables to the master. HTH and again Thanks Erik for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the Excel file is not present on the server, you can't use it in `OPENROWSET` or `OPENDATASOURCE` commands.

Using Access, however, you can use an insert query to insert data from the Excel file into SQL server:

```
INSERT INTO [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=logistics.companyname.com;Database=ITM;Trusted_Connection=Yes;].tmpWDWDLR
SELECT * 
FROM [Sheet1$] 
IN 'C:\Users\GONZW053\Documents\My Desktop Documents\Monster Database Exports\DTPM - WDW DLR\book1.xlsx'[Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=No;]
```

(`Sheet1$` is the range from the Excel file where you're moving things from)

As far as I know, this approach has relatively little overhead. Of course, moving around large files just takes time.

Comment: Erik, Thank you for the quick response. I got the same error message on this one too. Am I keeping the same line of code as above and just changing the strSQL and omitting the strXL line?

Comment: No, you just execute this directly in Access. Create a query, SQL view, paste, execute. That's it. The query itself includes all the connection things.

Comment: Great Thank you! This ran really fast.

Comment: Erik, When I run the query it does not append to the SERVER. Is there another method we should be using? I just ran a quick query in the server after hitting run in Access and 0 records. Also is there a way to include "First Row Has Headers"?

Comment: Change `HDR=Yes` instead of `HDR=No` to include headers. You can try to import an explicit range, such as `[Sheet1$A1:C100]`. Else Access will try to guess the range, and it might not find any records.

Comment: Erik, Thank you I am surprised I overlooked the HDR. I am running the query now to see how it goes. I will report back if there are any issues. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Erik, The query tries to execute but I now get the Run-Time Error 3035 System Resources exceeded. Is there another way to do this preferably through VBA?

Comment: You can execute queries through VBA using `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").Execute`

Comment: Erik, I thought about that and the method I am running with the line of code you provided is: Dim strSQL/strSQL="Your Code Provided"/docmd.runSQL (strSQL). You feel that doing it as a querydef will resolve the issue

Comment: Don't do `DoCmd.RunSQL`. That shows extra popups, caches it, etc. If you're going to execute an SQL string, use `CurrentDb.Execute`.

Comment: Erik, Thank you again. Ok so I have the following: Dim qdf as DAO.Querydef / Dim db as Dao.Database / Set qdf = currentDb.CreateQueryDef("queryname","sql statement provided") / CurrentDb.QueryDefs("queryname").execute

Comment: Don't dim anything. Don't set the querydef equal to a string, that generates a compile error. Just use `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").Execute` where `MyQuery` is the name of your query, as stored in Access. It's a single line. That's the same as executing the SQL string of that query through VBA.

Comment: Erik, Thanks, I will try this soon and report back. In short all I really want is to be able to import to the SQL Server from Access via VBA. Thanks again for all the help and quick responses :) You are awesome!

Comment: Erik, I tried to save the query in Access but it will not allow me to save the query.

Comment: Err... Didn't you already have the query saved? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Erik, I first popped it into the SQL Query designer and did "View Datasheet" gave results. Then I thought ok lets run this through VBA instead of storing this as another query on the front end. Then you advised me to not do that and do it as a stored query in Access and that's when I just now got a chance to throw it back into designer and tried to save it. It comes up with the "Save Query" box but the query doesn't save.

Comment: You should not view queries this complex in the designer. That leads to trouble. Limit it to SQL view only. You can use `CurrentDb.Execute` and execute the SQL string that way, if you wish, but query strings in VBA are often hard to adjust and debug.

Comment: Erik, In order for me to save the query I had to do INSERT INTO dbo_tmpWDWDLR and not the connection string.

Comment: Erik, sorry for the confusion. I did mean via designer in SQL view. Then to view if data was present then switched to datasheet view. But Alas with the connection string in the query it doesn't allow me to save the query in Access.